# "Genymotion quit unexpectedly" on Mac OS X Version 10.10.5 (14F27)

Tags: android, macos, virtualbox, genymotion

I have been trying to install Genymotion 2.7.2 for the last couple of days on a macbook. I have followed through various tutorials none of them helped.

I have installed virtualBox version 2.0.22, rebooted and then opened Genymotion .dmg file. Opening the app from the Applications folder gave me the following error and asks me to reopen.

I have tried doing it different ways but none of them worked. Is there something I've been doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of the error details]

Answer (score 6):

You can try to install [older version (2.6.0)](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.6.0/genymotion-2.6.0.dmg).

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug on the open SSL library. This crash at startup should be very random. If you reproduce the problem systematically please contact the support and give a maximum of information logs so we can study it.

Comment: This crash happens to me every time. What information logs would be best sent to you?

Comment: The content of the report you have on the screenshot here is the best thing.

Comment: ok, I'll forward it on - thanks (p.s., it's not my screenshot)

Comment: Any way to download 2.7.0 for example until this issue is fixed ? Having the same problem, upgraded to 2.7.2 and it's not starting.

Comment: This crash happens every single time. Don't say that "should be very random".