# Genymotion not opening after 2.7.2 update on mac

Tags: android, macos, genymotion

I am currently on the 10.11.4(El Capitan) update of the mac OSX. I downloaded the most recent version of Genymotion, but every time I try to open it I get an error message. It reads:

**genymotion quit unexpectedly.**

Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed  information and send a report to Apple.

I haven't been able to open Genymotion at all ever since. I tried to download an older version from the Genymotion site, but it only gives me links to the newest version. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988945/genymotion-quit-unexpectedly-on-mac-os-x-version-10-10-5-14f27)

However, you are right. Hitting the first link of the accepted answer takes you to Genymotion page where they prompt you to download the 2.7.2 version instead of 2.6.0

But if it is 2.6.0 version that you are looking to download and if that is the solution (as a similar question in StackOverflow answer tells us), you could download it [here](http://download.cnet.com/Genymotion/3000-18513_4-76475942.html)

**Note that the second link is from CNET and a lot of people might not be comfortable with that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that crash happens only on older Macs. Genymotion 2.7.0-2.7.2 includes OpenSSL library compiled for newer CPU's and crash with "Illegal instruction: 4" message.

Workaround for Genymotion 2.7.2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39260279/6780748)

[genymotion](/questions/tagged/genymotion) [osx](/questions/tagged/osx)